# Regex-How to split string by delimiter and if there is no delimiter return whole

Tags: regex, regex-group

I would like to extract some information from a string like below:

```
ksdfXX2344_vvs_gfedfg
ksdfXX2344
```

For example, to extract word `ksdfXX2344` from the string above.
Currently I have:

```
(.*?)(_.*)
```

which can extract the words in situation 1, but cannot extract the string with no delimiter `_`.
How can I extract the words if there are no delimiter inside?
Any suggestions?

Many thanks!

Comment: Which language/tool are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't split, replace:

```
Search: '_.*'
Replace: ''
```

eg in java:

```
String prefix = str.replaceAll("_.*", "");
```

or python:

```
prefix = re.sub(r'_.*', '', str)
```

---

To *match* only the prefix:

```
^[^_]*
```

this matches everything at the start that isn't an underscore, so the match will stop before the first underscore or end-of-input if there isn't an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
^[^_]+(?=_|$)
```

```
ksdfXX2344
```

The part

```
(?=_)
```

is a *positive look ahead*

See https://regex101.com/r/JPrilr/2

Comment: How do you know in advance if a delimiter is present? Perhaps `^[^_]+(?=_|$)`.

Comment: Thanks, but the first regex cannot extract the second situation. If I combine those two:[^_]+(?=_)|[^_]+, the second and third word behind '_' will also be extracted while I'm only expecting the first one, any suggestions?

Comment: Edited POST accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You could use the first capturing group with a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^_]+` and optionally `?` match an underscore followed by matching until the end of the string.

```
^([^_]+)(?:_.*)?$
```

See a [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PLXed9/1)